# Using ArcPy to insert new data into shapefile without editing it?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, cursor

I want to **insert new data into a empty shapefile**.
I have an array with the fields values of each row and I use InsertCursor to add these data to my shapefile.

When I run the code if **the shapefile is in edit form** I get the result, but if the shapefile **is not in editing form** I get nothing.

I want to achive the result in the second case, but I suppose that I have to create a newRow first and then use insertCursor.

The code is:

```
for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(a, ["SHAPE@XY"]):
cor = i[0]

p1=float(cor[0])+1.25, float(cor[1])-0.75
p2=float(cor[0])+1.25, float(cor[1])+0.75
p3=float(cor[0])-1.25, float(cor[1])+0.75
p4=float(cor[0])-1.25, float(cor[1])-0.75 

row_values=[((p1[0],p1[1]),1),((p2[0],p2[1]),1),((p3[0],p3[1]),1),((p4[0],p4[1]),1)]  #esto hay que mejorarlo para meter un FOR

cursor=arcpy.da.InsertCursor('points',['SHAPE@XY','Id'])

for row in row_values:
    cursor.insertRow(row)
```

Comment: You've got indentation flaws in your code sample. Plus, `row` appears to be used in both levels of nesting.

Comment: Yes @Vince, when I nest the code I use `i` instead of `row` in one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `InsertCursor` [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm):

> Opening simultaneous insert or update operations on the same workspace using different cursors requires the start of an edit session.

Since you're not closing the cursor, it remains open during the next run. 
Try using the following pattern instead:

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCuror('points', ['SHAPE@XY', 'Id']) as cursor:
    for row in row_values:
        cursor.insertRow(row)
```

This will automatically close the cursor at the end of the script.